# Not able to get the elemens of KendoDrop down - Selenium

Tags: css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

Using selenium web driver, me need to get the set of option values such as Last 30 days, Last 60 days etc.

I have tried to get those elements using CSS selector.

```
var timeperiodcss = "span.k-widget.k-dropdown.k-header select#selectDefaultTimePeriod option";

                var elements = element.FindElements(By.CssSelector(timeperiodcss));
                if (elements.Count >= 1)
                    break;
```

Every time elements.count is showing as 0. Not able to get those elements.

The following is the HTML content for those cases

```
<span class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header" style="width: 150px;" title="" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="selectDefaultTimePeriod_listbox" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="0936dfb5-4f8c-4dd4-826f-f802b6a719ff">
<span class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" unselectable="on">
<select id="selectDefaultTimePeriod" style="width: 150px; display: none;" data-bind="kendoDropDownList:timePeriodOptions" data-role="dropdownlist">
<option value="">Select time period</option>
<option value="Last 30 days">Last 30 days</option>
<option value="Last 60 days">Last 60 days</option>
<option value="Last 90 days" selected="selected">Last 90 days</option>
<option value="Last month">Last month</option>
<option value="Last quarter">Last quarter</option>
<option value="Last 6 months">Last 6 months</option>
<option value="Last 12 months">Last 12 months</option>
<option value="Last 365 days">Last 365 days</option>
<option value="Full year 2016">Full year 2016</option>
</select>
</span>
```

Please let me know, Is it have any other option to get those elements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you need to select all options one by one from this dropdown? 
Or get values from all options?
Or something else?

Comment: We need to get values from all options

Answer (score 0):

try this (code in C#)

```
 SelectElement selectElement = new SelectElement(WebDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("span.k-widget.k-dropdown.k-header select#selectDefaultTimePeriod")));
            foreach (var option in selectElement.Options)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(option.GetAttribute("value"));
            }
```

This css in only for selctor not for options.